# terraform delete rds instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

anyone knows if we can use terraform delete rds instance? There is a destroy command https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/destroy.html but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your terraform looks like and from the way you've worded your question I'm unsure if you have any, however, if you created the RDS instance via Terraform, then running `terraform destroy` will delete the RDS instance.

If you didn't create the instance in Terraform, you can import the instance and then run the `terraform destroy` command.

You can import by running the running the command shown [here.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#import)

Answer (score -1):

I have similar answer to @Nate. However I believe it is important to mention.

If you have your backend configured make sure you have the correct state file. This is usually done by running

```
terraform init
```

To remove the RDS and the resources you have created using terraform you should run the following;

```
terraform destroy -var-file=<name-of-the-file-with-vars> -auto-approve
```

It is important to provide the var-file and not to enter it manually.

Hope that helps slightly as well.

Comment: Nice answer but I would remove the -auto-approve option to avoid people that copy paste it to destroy resources without checking the output of the command before saying 'yes'